# Vim custom highlight not working

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm using [AfterColors](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641) and I'm trying to customise JavaScript conditional highlighting (the `if`, `else`, etc keywords are completely unhighlighted).

By looking at the `javascript.vim` syntax file that comes with vim, I saw the following line:

```
syn keyword javaScriptConditional   if else switch
```

I've tried adding the following without success:

```
hi javaScriptConditional ctermfg=9 guifg=#cc6666
```

I'm also using the [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) plugin, so I took a look at their syntax file too:

```
syntax keyword jsConditional    if else switch
```

I've then tried adding the following without success neither:

```
hi jsConditional ctermfg=9 guifg=#cc6666
```

What am I missing? I have plenty of colour customisations for CoffeeScript but for some reason it's not working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When JavaScript is *completely* unhighlighted, the *filetype* probably isn't set right. Check with `:setl ft?`; it needs to be `javascript`.

Also, with the default syntax script, conditionals should be linked to the `Conditional` highlight group.

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Lastly, you don't need the mentioned AfterColors plugin to just customize some syntax groups. The `:hi` commands in your `~/.vimrc` should be fine (unless you switch colorschemes on the fly). As I understand the plugin, that is to customize some *generic* highlight groups (like `Conditional` or `Statement`). Syntaxes should just `:syn link` to those.

Comment: I've edited the post for clarity. The `filetype` is ok, it's just the `if` keyword that remains blank. I've tried with `Conditional` but it didn't have any effect neither. About `AfterColors`, I used to have everything in my `vimrc`but installed the plugin just to have the styling rules separately. I'll try `SyntaxAttr`.

Comment: By using `SyntaxAttr`, I've discovered that `if` is part of the `javascriptComprehension` group for some reason, and highlighting that works as expected. I'll keep investigating the reason, thanks a lot!

Comment: The actual problem was that I was using two javascript plugins: `vim-javascript` and `yajs`, and that was not making the correct groups to get highlighted.